# the question of the formulation of the Dunford-Schwartz theorem about $l^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

According to the book Dunford-Schwartz, Linear Operators I, Theorem IV.8.16 the space $ (L^{\infty} (S, \Sigma, \nu))^*$  is isomorphic the space $ba (S, \Sigma_1, \| . \|)$. Unfortunately, I ran into the problem that I don't understand how the isomorphic mapping works. In  Dunford-Schwartz' book the isomorphism is shown as follows:
$$
F (l) = \int_{S} l(s) \lambda (ds),
$$
where $F \in L^{\infty} (S, \Sigma, \nu)^*, l \in L^{\infty} (S, \Sigma, \nu), \lambda \in 
 ba $. Moreover we know the relationship between $\lambda$ and $F$:
$$
\lambda (E) = F ( I_E ), ~ \text{for any} E \in \Sigma 
$$
where $I_E$ characteristic function of the set:
$$
I_E ( a ) = \left\{ \begin{aligned}
                  &1, ~ \text{if } a \in E \\
                  &0, ~ \text{if } a \notin E
\end{aligned} \right.
$$
Let's look at the set $l^{\infty} = L^{\infty} ( \mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}} )$ with standart counting metric. Now I can tell you what my question is. It is known $l^{\infty}$ is not reflexive in particular , there is $ \phi \in (l^{\infty})^*$ such that $ \phi (c) = 0 $, where $c$ is the space of sequences having a finite limit and $ \| \phi \| = 1 $. But for any $E \in 2^{\mathbb{N} }$ $ I_E $ is sequences having a finite limit it means that $\lambda(E) = 0$, but $\phi$ is not identically a null function.

I will be happy to see an explanation of how the said isomorphism works.

Edit: I made a mistake when describing the question. But unfortunately I haven't fully understood out this problem yet.

Metric in space $ba$ is total variation.It's easy to make sure $l_1 \subset ba$. Do I understand correctly that
$$
F(l) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} l(n) \lambda( \{ n \} )
$$
where $F \in (l^{\infty})^*, \lambda \in ba$ ?

In this case, we will choose $ l(n) = sign ( \lambda \{n\} ), \| l \| = 1 $ and
$$
F(l) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | \lambda( \{ n \} ) | \leq \| F \|
$$
it means $ \{ \lambda(\{ n \} ) \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in l^1 $ but $l^{1} $ is not reflexive.

Comment: $I_E$ has a limit if and only if it is eventually 0 or 1. There are many sets $E$ for which $I_E$ does not have a limit, for example the even numbers.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets , you are absolutely right. Can you take a look at my question addition, please? Because I still don't fully understand.

Comment: In general it does not hold that $F(l) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} l(n) \lambda( \{ n \} )$, as $\lambda$ is not $\sigma$-additive but only additive, so it does not hold that the measure of a countably infinite set is the sum of measures of its points.

Comment: Typical examples of functionals in $(\ell^\infty)^*$ which does not correspond to elements from $\ell^1$ are ultralimits (these are generalised limits which exist for any bounded sequence).

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets , but isn't the formula $ F(l) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} l (n) \lambda (\{ n\|) $ a particular consequence of the general formula (the first formula in my post) mentioned above?

Comment: I think it is not since $\lambda$ is not a (classical $\sigma$-additive) measure - for infinite $E$ we do not necessarily have $\lambda(E) = \sum_{e \in E} \lambda(\{e\})$.